# Why does my network connection fail when using a static address?

Tags: centos, ethernet, ip-address

When I try to change my IP address to static from DHCP, my internet connection goes off from centos.

```
Host os : MacOS High Sierra
VM : vmware fusion 
Guest OS :  CentOS Linux release 7.7.1908 (Core)
File : /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-ens33
```

Change :

```
TYPE="Ethernet"
PROXY_METHOD="none"
BROWSER_ONLY="no"
BOOTPROTO="none"
DEFROUTE="yes"
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL="no"
IPV6INIT="yes"
IPV6_AUTOCONF="yes"
IPV6_DEFROUTE="yes"
IPV6_FAILURE_FATAL="no"
IPV6_ADDR_GEN_MODE="stable-privacy"
NAME="ens33"
UUID="189d7c44-fc61-4597-a9c1-ee3c22d4feed"
DEVICE="ens33"
ONBOOT="yes
IPADDR=192.168.1.20 
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
GATEWAY=192.168.1.1
DNS1=8.8.8.8
DNS2=8.8.4.4"`
```

`

Commands used after change : `systemctl restart network`

Once the network restart done, there is no more net connectivity

Am i doing anything wrong

Static Ip a output :

```
user1@localhost ~]$ ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: ens33: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:0c:29:fb:3f:1b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.20/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global noprefixroute ens33
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::8384:7399:f191:5b47/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: virbr0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:11:b8:79 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.122.1/24 brd 192.168.122.255 scope global virbr0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: virbr0-nic: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast master virbr0 state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:11:b8:79 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
[user1@localhost ~]$
```

Static Ip route output :

```
[user1@localhost ~]$ ip route
default via 192.168.1.1 dev ens33 proto static metric 100 
192.168.1.0/24 dev ens33 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.20 metric 100 
192.168.122.0/24 dev virbr0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.122.1
```

DHCP IP a output

```
[user1@localhost ~]$ ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: ens33: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:0c:29:fb:3f:1b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.16.111.178/24 brd 172.16.111.255 scope global noprefixroute dynamic ens33
       valid_lft 1761sec preferred_lft 1761sec
    inet6 fe80::8384:7399:f191:5b47/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: virbr0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:11:b8:79 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.122.1/24 brd 192.168.122.255 scope global virbr0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: virbr0-nic: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast master virbr0 state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:11:b8:79 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
[user1@localhost ~]$
```

DHCP ip route output

```
[user1@localhost ~]$ ip route
default via 172.16.111.2 dev ens33 proto dhcp metric 100 
172.16.111.0/24 dev ens33 proto kernel scope link src 172.16.111.178 metric 100 
192.168.122.0/24 dev virbr0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.122.1 
[user1@localhost ~]$
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site! I think we need a little more info to try to help you out. What is the output from: `ip a` and `ip route show`?

Comment: thanks :) I have attached the screen shot of "ip a" and "ip route show" in the question now..

Comment: Please cut and paste the text into the question, it helps index the question which will get it more views and better answers. You can also post the output of the same commands when you have a DHCP lease. My guess is that the DHCP is not giving out 192.168.1.0/24 addresses but rather something else.

Comment: done user1794469!

Comment: What does it look like when you use DHCP though?

Comment: have added them in the question now :)

Answer (score 1):

You loose your internet connection because you are configuring your adapter on the wrong network.

When you use DHCP the DHCP router/server is giving you an address of:

```
172.16.111.0/24
```

and a default gateway of `172.16.111.2`.

When you configure it statically you have chosen the network:

```
192.168.1.0/24
```

with a default gateway of `192.168.1.1`. So while 192.168.1.1 is reachable from your configured network, the router/server isn't there. If you want to use a static address it needs to be on the same network as the router. Based on the DHCP configuration you should be able to choose any *unused* address on the `172.16.111.0/24`. In general this will be `172.16.111.1` through `172.16.111.255` but it looks like the router is using `172.16.111.2`. Frequently `172.16.111.1` is the router so there may be something else there. You could acquire a DHCP address and then use `nmap` to see what other addresses are used on the network.

Comment: ok great. So this is my understanding.Correct me if I am wrong


Point 1. During static ,My adapter is not in the network 192.168.1.0/24
Point 2. What needs to be done , to put the adapter in the correct network

Comment: You have it the other way around: the way you have configured your static address you have put your adapter on the 192.168.1.0/24 network which will only work on that network, which means the other devices on the network also have to be on that network which they are not. As evidence you can see that DHCP which works, is using the 172.16.111.0/24. If you change your adapter to use that network you will be set.

Answer (score 1):

It is as user1794469 has described it. your network access is via the 172.16.111.x network
The virbr0 that is configured in the 192.168.1.x network is internal to your computer, it is VirtualBridge0
It is used for virtualization and is likely from VM software.